# Simple neural network in c++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network

I have implemented a neural network in C++. But I'm not sure whether my implementation is correct or not. My code of the implementation of neural networks given bellow.
As an inexperienced programmer, I welcome any and all insights to improve my skill.

```
#include "csv.h"
using namespace rapidcsv;
using namespace std;


class Neuron;
struct connection{
    connection(int i){
        weight=a_weight=0;
        id=i;
    }
    void weight_val(double w){
        weight=w;
    }
    void weight_acc(double a){
        a_weight+=a;
    }
    void reset(){
        a_weight=0.0;
    };
    void move(double m,double alpha,double lambda){
        weight=weight-alpha*a_weight/m-lambda*weight;
    }
    double weight,a_weight;
    int id=0;
};
typedef vector <Neuron> layer;
class Neuron{
public:
    Neuron(int idx,int nxt_layer_size){
        n_id=idx;
        for(int i=0;i<nxt_layer_size;i++){
            n_con.push_back(connection(i));
            n_con[i].weight_val(rand()/double(RAND_MAX));
        }
        set_val(0.0);
        is_output_neuron=false;
    }

    void hypothesis(layer &prev_layer){
        double sm=0;
        for(int i=0;i<prev_layer.size();i++){
            sm+=prev_layer[i].get_val()*prev_layer[i].get_con(n_id).weight;
        }
        set_val(sigmoid(sm));
        if(is_output_neuron){
            cost+=target*log(get_val())+(1-target)*log(1-get_val());
        }
    }

    void calc_delta(layer next_layer={}){
        if(is_output_neuron||next_layer.size()==0){
            delta=get_val()-target;
        }else{
            double sm=0;
            delta=delta_dot(next_layer)*sigmoid_prime(get_val());
        }
    }
    void calc_grad(layer &nxt_layer){
        for(int i=0;i<nxt_layer.size()-1;i++){
            n_con[i].weight_acc(get_val()*nxt_layer[i].get_delta());
        }
    }

    double flush_cost(){
        double tmp=cost;
        cost=0;
        return tmp;
    }

    double get_delta(){
        return delta;
    }
    void set_target(double x){
        target=x;
        is_output_neuron=true;
    }
    double get_val(){
        return a;
    }
    void set_val(double x){
        a=x;
    }

    void update_weight(double m,double alpha,double lambda){
        for(int i=0;i<n_con.size();i++){
            n_con[i].move(m,alpha,lambda);
            n_con[i].reset();
        }
    }


    connection get_con(int idx){
        return n_con[idx];
    }
private:
    int n_id;double a;
    vector <connection> n_con;
    static double sigmoid(double x){
        return 1.0/(1+exp(-x));
    }
    static double sigmoid_prime(double x){
        return x*(1-x);
    }
    double delta_dot(layer nxt_layer){
        assert(nxt_layer.size()-1==n_con.size());
        double sm=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n_con.size();i++){
            sm+=n_con[i].weight*nxt_layer[i].get_delta();
        }
        return sm;
    }
    double target,delta,cost=0;bool is_output_neuron;
};
class Network{
public:
    Network(vector <int> arch){
        srand(time(0));
        for(int i=0;i<arch.size();i++){
            int nxt_layer_size=i==arch.size()-1?0:arch[i+1];
            layer tmp;
            for(int j=0;j<=arch[i];j++){
                tmp.push_back(Neuron(j,nxt_layer_size));
            }
            tmp.back().set_val(1.0);
            n_layers.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
    vector <double> feed_forward(vector <double> in,bool output=false){
        vector <double> ot;
        assert(in.size()==n_layers[0].size()-1);
        for(int i=0;i<in.size();i++){
            n_layers[0][i].set_val(in[i]);
        }
        for(int i=1;i<n_layers.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n_layers[i].size()-1;j++){
                n_layers[i][j].hypothesis(n_layers[i-1]);
            }

        }
        if(output) {
            for(int i=0;i<n_layers.back().size()-1;i++){
                ot.push_back(n_layers.back()[i].get_val());
            }
        }
        return ot;
    }
    void feed_backward(vector <double> ot){
        assert(ot.size()==n_layers.back().size()-1);
        for(int i=0;i<ot.size();i++){
            n_layers.back()[i].set_target(ot[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n_layers.back().size()-1;i++){
            n_layers.back()[i].calc_delta();
        }

        for(int i=n_layers.size()-2;i>=0;i--){
            for(auto &a:n_layers[i]){
                a.calc_delta(n_layers[i+1]);
                a.calc_grad(n_layers[i+1]);
            }
        }

    }
    void done(double m){
        for(unsigned i=0;i<n_layers.size();i++){
            for(unsigned j=0;j<n_layers[i].size();j++){
                n_layers[i][j].update_weight(m,alpha,lambda);
            }
        }
    }

    double calc_cost(){
        for(int i=0;i<n_layers.back().size()-1;i++){
            cost_acc+=n_layers.back()[i].flush_cost();
        }
        return cost_acc;
    }
    double get_cost(double m){
        double tmp=cost_acc;
        cost_acc=0;
        return -tmp/m;
    }
    void set_hyper_params(double alpha,double lambda){
        this->alpha=alpha;
        this->lambda=lambda;
    }
private:
    vector <layer> n_layers;
    double cost_acc=0,alpha,lambda;
};

int main() {

    Network net({4,5,3});

    net.set_hyper_params(0.1,0.0);

    Document doc("../dataset.csv");
    vector <double> x1=doc.GetColumn<double>("x1");
    vector <double> x3=doc.GetColumn<double>("x3");
    vector <double> x4=doc.GetColumn<double>("x4");
    vector <double> x2=doc.GetColumn<double>("x2");
    vector <double> y=doc.GetColumn<double>("y");
vector <double> lrc;
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<x1.size();j++){
            net.feed_forward({x1[j],x2[j],x3[j],x4[j]});
            vector <double> ot;
            ot.push_back(y[j]==0);
            ot.push_back(y[j]==1);
            ot.push_back(y[j]==2);
            net.feed_backward(ot);
            net.calc_cost();

        }
        double cst=net.get_cost(x1.size());
        lrc.push_back(cst);
        if(i%100==0) cout<<"Cost="<<cst<<"/i="<<i<<endl;
        net.done(x1.size());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Rapid Csv](https://github.com/d99kris/rapidcsv) [Iris dataset](https://github.com/me-sharif-hasan/Machine-learnign-algo-from-scratch/blob/master/iris/dataset.csv)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks plausible. The two biggest pieces of advice I have for you are:

- Format your code consistently and idiomatically! One easy way to do this is to use the `clang-format` tool on it. A more tedious, but rewarding, way is to study other people's code and try to emulate their style. For example, you should instinctively write `vector<T>`, not `vector <T>`.
- It sounds like you're not sure if your code behaves correctly. For that, you should use **unit tests**. Figure out what it would mean — what it would look like — for a small part of your code to "behave correctly," and then write a small test that verifies that what you expect is actually what happens. Repeat many times.

---

Stylistically: Don't do `using namespace std;`. Every C++ programmer will tell you this. (Why not? There are reasons, but honestly the best reason is because everyone agrees that you shouldn't.)

Forward-declaring `class Neuron;` above `struct connection` is strange because `connection` doesn't actually need to use `Neuron` for anything.

`connection(int i)` defines an *implicit* constructor, such that the following line will compile and do an implicit conversion:

```
connection conn = 42;
```

You don't want that. So mark this constructor `explicit`. (In fact, mark *all* constructors `explicit`, except for the two that you want to happen implicitly — that is, copy and move constructors. *Everything* else should be explicit.)

`weight_val` and `weight_acc` look like they should be called `set_weight` and `add_weight`, respectively. Use noun phrases for things that are nouns (variables, types) and verb phrases for things that are verbs (functions). Also, avd unnec. abbr'n.

...Oooh! `weight_val` and `weight_acc` actually modify *different data members!* That was sneaky. Okay, from the formula in `move`, it looks like we've got a sort of an "alpha weight" and a "lambda weight"? I bet these have established names in the literature. So instead of `weight_val(x)` I would call it `set_lambda_weight(x)` (or whatever the established name is); instead of `weight_acc(x)` I would call it `add_alpha_weight(x)`; and instead of `reset` I would call it `set_alpha_weight(0)`.

Further down, you use `get_val()` and `set_val(x)` to get and set a member whose actual name is `a`. Pick one name for one concept! If its proper name is `a`, call the methods `get_a()` and `set_a(a)`. If its proper name is `val`, then name it `val`.

---

```
void done(double m){
    for(unsigned i=0;i<n_layers.size();i++){
        for(unsigned j=0;j<n_layers[i].size();j++){
            n_layers[i][j].update_weight(m,alpha,lambda);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the name of this method doesn't seem to indicate anything about its purpose. `x.done()` sounds like we're asking if `x` is done — it doesn't sound like a mutator method. Seems to me that the function should be called `update_all_weights`.

The body of this function can be written simply as

```
void update_all_weights(double m) {
    for (Layer& layer : n_layers) {
        for (Neuron& neuron : layer) {
            neuron.update_weight(m, alpha, lambda);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that to distinguish the name of the *type* `Layer` from the name of the *variable* `layer`, I had to uppercase the former. You already uppercased `Neuron`, so uppercasing `Layer` should be a no-brainer.

---

```
weight=weight-alpha*a_weight/m-lambda*weight;
```

This formula is impossible to read without some whitespace. Look how much clearer this is:

```
weight = weight - alpha*a_weight/m - lambda*weight;
```

And then we can rewrite it as:

```
weight -= ((alpha/m) * a_weight) + (lambda * weight);
```

I might even split that up into two subtractions, if I knew I wasn't concerned about floating-point precision loss.

```
weight -= (alpha/m) * a_weight;
weight -= lambda * weight;
```

---

```
double weight,a_weight;
```

clang-format will probably do this for you (I hope!), but please: one declaration per line!

```
double weight;
double a_weight;
```

---

That should be enough nitpicking to give you something to do.

Comment: "There are reasons, but honestly the best reason is because everyone agrees that you shouldn't." I would at least provide one reason: to prevent namespace/typename collisions.